# Android/PHP JSON API Url StringBuilder

Tags: java, php, android

How can i add string in my url? For example:

```
String Password="123";
String UserName="şlk";

HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://192.168.2.245/getProducts.php?login=1&user_name=UserName&user_pass=Password");
```

but it gives error by this way. How can it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple String operation:

```
String url = "http://192.168.2.248/getProducts.php?login=1&user_name="+ UserName + "&user_pass=" + Password;
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
```

Please get to know Java a little more, buy you a book and keep on googleing!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply by + operator

HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(
                    "URL/getProducts.php?login=1&user_name="+UserName+"&user_pass="+Password);

Comment: If your String contains some spaces than encode that string first before adding to url by
String username = URLEncode.encode(string);

Comment: And I ask myself: 
 "Where is my mind? :)  Thank you .

Comment: Thank you also @Muhammad Ali Hassan for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

use concatenation operator it is "+"  in java "." in `php`

```
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("...&user_name="+UserName+"&user_pass="+Password);
```

please read java before using it. style guide as well.